# Pyspark - Reject Values based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with values:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|1
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|2
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|3
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|4
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|5
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|6
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|7
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|8
|      XXXXXXXX|               |                 1|   000000001|9
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|10
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|11
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|12
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|13
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|14
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|15
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|16
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|17
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000000|18
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|19
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000001|20
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|21
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|22
|      ZZZZZZZZ|               |                 2|   000000001|23
```

Each registerNumber represents set of records.
Where `joint_indicator` is `1`, it represents joint shareholding and where it's blank it represents individual shareholder.
First `1` `joint_indicator` starts the joint holding and must have total `no_of_shares` held (must be greater than zero), all subsequent records must have 0 `no_of_shares`.

Reject Values For Conditions:

1. When the `joint_indicator` is blank, the `no_of_shares` will be greater than 0, the next record after that with `joint_indicator` being populated, the `no_of_shares` shouldn't be 0 and it's a error record.
   Example:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|      XXXXXXXX|               |                 1|   000000001|9    |
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|10   |
```

2. For 2nd set of records First `1` `joint_indicator` starts the joint holding and have total `no_of_shares` held (must be greater than zero), all subsequent records must have 0 `no_of_shares`.
   Here subsequent record isn't equal to 0. So this is also a error record
   Example:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|16
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|17
```

Whereas this shouldn't give me an error:
Example:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|16
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000000|17
```

I am suppose to fetch `registerNumber` for the error records
Any leads to solve this would be highly appreciated.
Expected Output:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+-------+
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|error  |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+-------+
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    1|  false| 
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    2|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    3|  false| 
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    4|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    5|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    6|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    7|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    8|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|           null|                 1|   000000001|    9|  false| 
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   10|   true| 
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   11|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|   12|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   13|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|   14|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   15|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   16|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   17|  true |
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|   22|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000000|   18|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   19|  true |
|      ZZZZZZZZ|           null|                 2|   000000001|   23|  false|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000001|   20|  false|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|   21|  false|
```

Comment: Is `registerNumber` an increasing index? If one value of `registerNumber` is `n`, is the following value necessarily `n+1`?

Comment: ```registerNumber``` is constant for a set of records. There can be another set with different ```registerNumbers```

Comment: @Oli I have edited the question for ease of understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, a record is in error if:

- the previous `joint_indicator` is null and `no_of_shares` is `0`
- the previous `joint_indicator` is not null, the previous `no_of_shares` is not `0` and the current `no_of_shares` is not `0`.
- the `joint_indicator` is not null, `no_of_shares` is not 0 and it is the last one (we check that the next id is null in the window)

You can simply check that with a window ordered by `mn_id` and partitioned by `registerNumber` like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
win = Window.partitionBy("registerNumber").orderBy("mn_id")

result = df\
  .withColumn("error_1",
       F.lag("joint_indicator").over(win).isNull() &
       F.col("no_of_shares").rlike("^0+$")
  ).withColumn("error_2",
       F.lag("joint_indicator").over(win).isNotNull() &
       ~F.col("no_of_shares").rlike("^0+$") &
       ~F.lag(F.col("no_of_shares")).over(win).rlike("^0+$")
  ).withColumn("error_3",
       F.col("joint_indicator").isNotNull() &
       ~F.col("no_of_shares").rlike("^0+$") &
       F.lead("mn_id").over(win).isNull()
  )
result.show(30)
```

```
|registerNumber|joint_indicator|share_class_number|no_of_shares|mn_id|error_1|error_2|error_3|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    1|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    2|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    3|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    4|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    5|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    6|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|    7|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|    8|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|           null|                 1|   000000001|    9|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   10|   true|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   11|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|   12|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   13|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000001|   14|  false|  false|  false|
|      XXXXXXXX|              1|                 1|   000000000|   15|  false|  false|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   16|  false|  false|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   17|  false|   true|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000000|   18|  false|  false|  false|
|      YYYYYYYY|              1|                 1|   000000001|   19|  false|  false|   true|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000001|   20|  false|  false|  false|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|   21|  false|  false|  false|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|              1|                 2|   000000000|   22|  false|  false|  false|
|      ZZZZZZZZ|           null|                 2|   000000001|   23|  false|  false|  false|
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

I separated the 3 error cases for clarity. You may then do

```py
result = result\
    .withColumn("error", F.col("error_1") | F.col("error_2") | F.col("error_3"))\
    .drop("error_1", "error_2", "error_3")
```

Comment: The first scenario looks good but for second scenario. It's something like:
For same ```registerNumber``` and with joint_indicator value isn't null no two consecutive ```no_of_shares``` has value greater than 0.

Comment: I have added the scenarios in question where it should give error and where it shouldn't.

Comment: I added a condition for `error_2`. Let me know if that's what you expect. If not, feel free to post the exact output you expect (the full dataframe).

Comment: Thanks @Oli for the solution. But there's a catch here: "First 1 joint_indicator starts the joint holding and have total no_of_shares held (must be greater than zero), all subsequent records must have 0 no_of_shares". If you see for `registerNumber` - `YYYYYYYY` the last record of that set has `no_of_shares` = 1 and `joint_indicator` is also 1, but it doesn't have a subsequent record with 0 `no_of_shares`, so that should also give an error . I have added the expected output dataframe in question.

Comment: I added the third case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lets call your dataframe to be `df`

```
df = df.select('registerNumber').filter("joint_indicator is not null").filter(df.no_of_shares = 0)
```

This should give you a dataframe with above said condition.

Comment: This wouldn't give me expected output since it will give me all the records where no_of_shares is 0 and joint_indicator isn't blank.